# Showing small standard deviation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following bar chart, where the standard deviation is too small to be seen. The y axis uses the log-scale. Is it possible to configure the script to show the standard deviation?

[image]

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from collections import namedtuple
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

NS_FILE = '..\\overhead.csv'

OUTPUT_PATH = '..\\'

sboti = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[1], names=['sboti'])
sboti_nds = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[2], names=['sboti_nds'])
greedy = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[3], names=['greedy'])
simdijkstra = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[4], names=['simdijkstra'])
random = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[5], names=['random'])

sboti_stdev = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[7], names=['sboti_stdev'])
sboti_nds_stdev = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[8], names=['sboti_nds_stdev'])
greedy_stdev = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[9], names=['greedy_stdev'])
simdijkstra_stdev = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[10], names=['simdijkstra_stdev'])
random_stdev = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=NS_FILE, header=None, usecols=[11], names=['random_stdev'])

sboti_list = sboti['sboti'].values.tolist()
sboti_nds_list = sboti_nds['sboti_nds'].values.tolist()
greedy_list = greedy['greedy'].values.tolist()
simdijkstra_list = simdijkstra['simdijkstra'].values.tolist()
random_list = random['random'].values.tolist()

sboti_stdev_list = sboti_stdev['sboti_stdev'].values.tolist()
sboti_nds_stdev_list = sboti_nds_stdev['sboti_nds_stdev'].values.tolist()
greedy_stdev_list = greedy_stdev['greedy_stdev'].values.tolist()
simdijkstra_stdev_list = simdijkstra_stdev['simdijkstra_stdev'].values.tolist()
random_stdev_list = random_stdev['random_stdev'].values.tolist()

n_groups = 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.set_size_inches(10.5, 4.5, forward=True)

plt.yticks(fontsize=24)

index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.55

error_config = {'ecolor': '0.3'}

ax.grid(which='major', axis='y', linestyle='--') 

ax.bar(index, sboti_list, bar_width/5, color='r', 
       yerr=sboti_stdev_list, error_kw=error_config, label='Sboti')

ax.bar(index + bar_width * 0.25, sboti_nds_list, bar_width/5, color='cornflowerblue', 
       yerr=sboti_nds_stdev_list, error_kw=error_config, label='Sboti_nds')

ax.bar(index + bar_width * 0.5, greedy_list, bar_width/5, color='g', 
       yerr=greedy_stdev_list, error_kw=error_config, label='GoCoMo')

ax.bar(index + bar_width * 0.75, simdijkstra_list, bar_width/5, color='yellow', 
       yerr=simdijkstra_stdev_list, error_kw=error_config, label='SimDijkstra')

ax.bar(index + bar_width * 1.0, random_list, bar_width/5, color='orange', 
       yerr=random_stdev_list, error_kw=error_config, label='Random')

ax.set_xlabel('Configuration Size', fontsize=24, fontweight="bold")
ax.set_ylabel('Communication \n Overhead (#)', fontsize=24, fontweight="bold")
ax.set_xticks(index + bar_width * 0.6)
ax.set_xticklabels(('k=2', 'k=3', 'k=4', 'k=5'), fontsize=26)
ax.legend()

plt.legend(['SBOTI', 'SBOTI-NDS', 'GoCoMo', 'SimDijkstra', 'Random'],
           fontsize=24, loc='upper center', ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1.225, 1.05), 
           borderpad=0.5, edgecolor='black', fancybox=False, handletextpad=0.05)


ax.set_yscale('log',nonposy='clip')
plt.ylim([0.0, 1000000.0])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(join(OUTPUT_PATH, 'overhead_plot_final.pdf'), bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The content of overhead.csv:

```
k2,37460.22,37460.42,5928.02,60.56,352.26,,21.92593283334245,25.202923380805963,3128.397082487178,20.88858686518764,242.4525040800649
k3,99930.06,99932.76,4358.62,25.2,217.42,,76.54621386549994,82.02651636973927,516.8570595435453,5.941895526595833,26.101911729188863
k4,212409.94,212406.28,9603.56,29.5,430.18,,166.80495881632027,153.9937767096649,7.52725659432005,9.653697610295259,17.54724235558722
k5,416936.9,416930.14,18754.28,35.04,844.4,,31.603571226773,29.936674661623975,4.549231825713175,10.540417836275054,31.93040902350239
```

Comment: *How* do you envision to show the standard deviation?

Comment: In a way that will be seen that exists.

Comment: But how should it look like?

Comment: Preferably something like the green, yellow and orange bars from the first group. Which it does at the moment, but it is very small. I'm wondering if it is possible to something without changing the scale

Comment: Well, but if the standard deviation is as small as it is, it cannot look like the one from the smaller bars. Do you want to show some number other than the standard deviation?

Comment: The problem is that on a logarithmic scale your standard deviations are too small to take up many pixels - i.e. you can't see them very well. The higher / larger your bars are, the more compressed the standard deviation values become. On a side note, you should need to do convert your dataframe columns to a list each time - matplotlib will do the right thing if you just give it the column.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will try to increase the thinkness of the bar/ width of the cap to see how it looks

Comment: @TomJohnson An example will be very useful, as I'm still learning matplotlib

Comment: Please see my answer below for an example. Good luck.

Comment: @TomJohnson Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code that looks like this:

```
sboti_list = sboti['sboti'].values.tolist()
sboti_stdev_list = sboti_stdev['sboti_stdev'].values.tolist()
ax.bar(index, sboti_list, bar_width/5, color='r', 
       yerr=sboti_stdev_list, error_kw=error_config, label='Sboti')
```

by deleting the first two lines that are converting the dataframe columns to a list and use

```
ax.bar(index, sboti['sboti'], bar_width/5, color='r', 
       yerr=sboti_stdev['sboti_stdev'], error_kw=error_config, label='Sboti')
```

instead. This will clean up some of the code clutter.